# Unity android build with obb scene not loading

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, google-analytics

-Unity: 5.6.0f3

-Android API & Build Tools: 26

-Google Analytics: V4 bitcode package

Our game is finished and we are trying to publish it to the Play Store. As a single .apk file it exceeds the size limit so we have to use "Split application binary" to split our app into an .apk and .obb file. However, this causes the second scene to not load on some older Android versions/devices (Samsung Galaxy S5 Neo with Android 6.0.1, Samsung Galaxy S6 Edge with Android 7.0.0, ...). The first scene loads and works correctly but as soon as the second scene is supposed to load nothing happens anymore. adb logcat does not return any errors when this happens. On newer devices (Samsung Galaxy S8 with Android 8.0.0, ...) this is not a problem.

A suggested solution for people with similar issues is to use READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE in the AndroidManifest. This fixes the issue on the older devices, but it causes the app to crash on load on newer devices with error message "Unable to query for permission: Fragment null must be a public static class to be properly recreated from instance state."

After updating to Android Build Tools version 26, the Resolver included in the Google Analytics plugin updated the files under "Assets/Plugins/Android" and we were able to make a build that works on both the older and newer devices so it seems these files were part of the problem. We are not sure however what exactly caused the problem and if this update is a permanent fix. Also, when trying to pinpoint the problem further and having reverted certain settings the build still ran into this problem on the older devices despite the updated android files. Has anyone experienced this problem and found where exactly it is coming from + a lasting solution?